# How does KSQL read(consume msgs) data from a topic, already containing some messages

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have created a stream from Kafka using KSQL for a Kafka topic which already contains some messages. But not receiving any msg from that topic into stream created. 
Messages are in Avro format and generated after some interval.

I want to read from starting i.e. from earliest msg. Also tried setting offset property to earliest but not receiving any msg.

`create stream sample_transition with(topic_name='transition',value_format='avro');`

Comment: Are you getting any data when running this command in console: kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic TOPIC-NAME --from-beginning

Comment: @Ritu : It will be better if you could share your KSQL stream query and topic details .

Comment: @MehulGupta : topic name - transition, stream - create stream sample_transition with(topic_name='transition',value_format='avro');

Comment: @Ritu : I have tried this multiple times, this works fine. I would suggest to check the details again could be a small mistake which caused this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `auto.offset.reset` configuration correctly. Be default it's "latest". If you want new queried to read all data from a topic, you need to set it to "earliest".

```
ksql> SET 'auto.offset.reset'='earliest';
```

Compare: https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/installation/server-config/config-reference.html#ksql-streams-auto-offset-reset

Comment: Seems Ritu has already tried this option. She is facing some other issue